# Using XPath to find list of text fields

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, scrapy

Using scrapy and given this HTML code

```
<div class="parts"> 
<b>Part1 :</b> 
<a href='/part1.htm'>name 1</a> 
<br> 
<b> Part2 : </b> 
<a href='/part21.htm'>name 21</a>, 
<a href='/part22.htm'>name 22</a>, 
<a href='/part23.htm'>name 23</a>
<br> 
<b> Part3 : </b> 
<a href='/parts31.htm'>name 31</a>, 
<a href='/part32.htm'>name 32</a> 
<br>
</div>
```

I would like to extract each series of names after each `<b>` section.

For the first one (where there is only one name) it works with this

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="parts"]/b[contains(text(),"Part1")]/following::a/text()').extract_first()
```

this results in 'name 1'

For the second one, I expected the following to give me a list with 'name 21', 'name 22' and 'name 23' i.e. stopping before the next b tag but the list returned contains also 'name 31' and 'name 32'

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="parts"]/b[contains(text(),"Part2")]/following::a/text()')
```

How can I limit the list to only what's after the 'Part2' b tag and before the 'Part3' b tag?

Comment: `/following::a` selects all `a` elements that occur anywhere in the document after the `<b>` tag.

Comment: So, you can use this alternative way response.xpath('//div[@class="parts"]//a[contains(@href, "/part2")]/text()').extract()

Comment: My example differs from my real situation in that the different partX and nameX are random strings, so I cannot use starpony suggestion which works if all hrefs of the second block contain "/part2"

Comment: @Archipelago Why don't you show your example as it is? You'd get the right answer a lot faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to select all of the `text()` children of the `<a>` between the `<b>` that contains `Part2` and the `<b>` that contains `Part3`:

```
/div/b[contains(., 'Part2')]/following-sibling::a[following-sibling::b[contains(.,'Part3')]]/text()
```

Another way would be to select all of the `text()` children of the `<a>` that are following-siblings of the `<b>` that contain `Part2` and who's first preceding-sibling `<b>` contains `Part2`:

```
/div/b[contains(., 'Part2')]/following-sibling::a[preceding-sibling::b[1][contains(.,'Part2')]]/text()
```

Comment: Thanks Mads Hansen I tried your first suggestion  and it works. I understand your syntax gets all the texts between the two b tags; would you be kind enough to show me how to get the last names ('name 31' and 'name 32') as this very method cannot apply as there is not 'Part 4' b block..

Comment: The second XPath would apply, just change `Part2` to `Part3`: `/div/b[contains(., 'Part3')]/following-sibling::a[preceding-sibling::b[1][contains(.,'Part3')]]/text()`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use another approach: just get ALL names and for each name get corresponding `<b>` section:

```
data = {}
for name_node in response.xpath('//div[@class="parts"]/a'):
    name = name_node.xpath('./text()').extract_first()
    section_name = name_node.xpath('./preceding-sibling::b[1]/text()').extract_first()

    if section_name not in data:
        data[section_name] = []
    data[section_name].append(name)

print(data["Part2 :"][1])
```